# Не могу получить сумму всех элементов, не понимаю что не так

Tags: python

```
def n(*num):
    s=num[0]
    for i in num:
        s+=i
    return s

print(n([5,6,7,8]))
```

Comment: `print(sum([5,6,7,8]))`

Comment: Не так то, что вы инициализируете переменную s значением из первого элемента, а потом прибавляете все элементы (в том числе и первый элемент еще раз).

Answer (score 2):

`def n(*num):` → `def n(num):`

`s=num[0]` → `s = 0`

Comment: Попробовал, получилась сумма на 2 больше  чем должна

Comment: с этими данными должна быть больше на 5 (если точнее, то на n[0], который тут 5). Добавил еще поправку.

Comment: Все работает,  Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

```
def n(num):
    s = 0
    for i in num:   
        s += i
    return s

print(n([5,6,7,8])) # 26
```